# Runaan's Hurricane effects for these champions

Tags: league-of-legends

How exactly does Runaan's Hurricane work for:

- Draven, spinning axe
- Jayce, transform mercury cannon
- Jayce, hyper charge
- Jinx, fishbones
- Kayle, righteous fury
- Kennen, electric surge
- Lulu, pix
- Orianna, clockwork windup
- Vayne, silver bolts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abilities that only apply to the projectile fired at the primary target:

- Spinning Axe
- Transform: Mercury Cannon
- Righteous Fury
- Silver Bolts
- Pix
- Clockwork Windup

Abilities that affect the primary and secondary targets:

- Hyper Charge
- Fishbones
- Electric Surge (Mark of the Storm proc only, not the bonus damage)

**Rule of thumb for Runaan's bolts applying something:** If it's "on next hit", or can only generate stacks on one unit at a time (Sheen, Silver Bolts, Clockwork Windup; but not Mark of the Storm) it only applies to the main target. If it's on every autoattack, it *probably* will apply to all targets hit.

Lots more interactions listed here: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Runaan%27s_Hurricane

Comment: This is true. Although, the only champion that is viable with a runaans is Kayle.   It may work on others for offbuilds, but youre just gimping yourself compared to more optimal builds.