# Does Runaan's Hurricane apply on hit effects in TFT?

Tags: teamfight-tactics

In LoL, Runaan's Hurricane applies on-hit effects as seen in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/190137/216367).

---

Does [Runaan's Hurricane](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Template:TFT_Data/Runaan%27s_Hurricane) also apply on-hit effects in Teamfight Tactics?

Specifically, I'm wondering about item-based on-hit effects (e.g. [Red Buff](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Template:TFT_Data/Red_Buff)) and a on-hit effects from a champion's passive (e.g [Vayne's Silver Bolts](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Teamfight_Tactics:Vayne)).

I've looked at the linked LoL Wiki pages but those only list the in-game description without additional details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tested Runnans on Vayne in Team Fight Tactics 8/9/19. It works. Applies silver bolts on 3 units.

Comment: To complete your answer, the Runnan apply every on-hit effect  like Vayne's passiv since [patch 9.14](https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/teamfight-tactics-patch-914-notes)

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as I'm pretty sure the Gunsligner passive do apply on hit effects, I would guess it does.

Answer (score 0):

Runaan's applies on-hits. *However*, as with regular League, Vayne's passive does not interact with Runaan's.

Comment: Thanks, is there a general rule about champions' passives or does it depend on the champ?

Comment: It's by champion, but Vayne is a special exception.

Comment: It does also NOT apply the Mana steal passive from Kassadin. Just tried it

Comment: This is currently in rework. On PBE, runnan's currently applies Vayne passive on 3 targets